# Flag declined on low quality post

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

I just want to know why my flag was declined, so I know not to make the same mistake again.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898580/display-calendar-in-java) (you'll need 10K+ to view it) was just as follows:

> I am trying to display a calendar in Java for a specific year and
>   month, so that the user is able to select any month and any year. How
>   could I implement this code?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

From the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work
>   you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the
>   difficulty you are having solving it.

I didn't know if this was a homework question. I did know that the question didn't show any effort or thought - all it did was ask for code to be given. I could have marked the question as off-topic and cited the reason above, but I chose simply low quality.

Why was my flag declined?

ALSO, a small secondary question - the post was deleted for "Moderation Reasons." I thought I had read that when posts are deleted or placed on hold after you place a flag, the flag is automatically awarded a "Helpful" status. Is that not true? If not, how does it work?

EDIT: I appreciate George's response, but I still don't see this question as resolved. His answer only brings a new one up for me, so I'm adding it here. If the informal defintion for very low quality is:

> VLQ means the flagger thinks this post is beyond saving -- no amount of editing or polishing will turn this particular turd into gold. It is a call for a pooper-scooper.

and this is the reason the flag was declined, what sort of editing can I do in the future to improve a post that says "I want code to do ______."

Comment: I just followed some of the links listed under related and found them very revealing.

Answer (score 7):

I declined it [because 'very low quality' has a very specific meaning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous):

> VLQ means the flagger thinks this post is beyond saving -- no amount of editing or polishing will turn this particular turd into gold. It is a call for a pooper-scooper.

That's the criteria I use to accept or decline a flag that is 'Very Low Quality' (note the 'very').  In this case, this question is not beyond saving, and it's not so terrible that a moderator should delete it immediately.  That's what you're asking us to do when you flag a post as "Very Low Quality" --  you're asking us to delete the post immediately.

In this case, the community elected to handle it; and there was no need for a moderator to get involved.

I can see a few ways the question can be improved through editing; and those are steps I'd encourage you to take over asking a moderator to nuke it.

Comment: All right. So to get it straight - if I choose VLQ, it goes to you to review. If I choose Off Topic, it goes to community review?

Comment: What sort of editing could I do to improve the question? That question seems unfixable to me - "Please provide code that does ________." What can a user, other than the author of the question, add to improve that? And what can I do to improve a post like that in the future?

Comment: @AlexK When you're advocating instantaneous deletion you're saying that *even the author of the post* couldn't fix the question.  That's a question you should downvote and vote to close, but give the author an opportunity to try to fix before deletion.  If he doesn't take the time to fix it, the automatic cleanup script will delete it after it has been closed for some time.

Comment: @Servy I wish everyone who flagged VLQ understood that!!

Comment: … this ignores the existence of the LQRQ.

Comment: @bjb568 has a point. While flagging as "very low quality" probably was the wrong this to do here, [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) suggests that the flag will throw the post in the queue, contrary to your answer: "It also contains posts that have been flagged for being extremely low-quality and answers flagged for not being proper answers." Is that post up to date, or has something changed? Is there there some finer point we're missing?

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, they go into the queue but moderators also see them and can process them.  That's what happened here, a mod saw the flag, and declined it.