# Declined flag on link-only answer

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, link-only-answers

I know we have very similar topics on a regular basis. I thought the definition of a "link-only answer" had been fairly well established, mainly based on @Shog9's canonical [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

But a flag I just got declined makes me question either my own judgement, or whether these policies are consistently enforced. I flagged this answer: [OpenGL 4 core profile, shaders and MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949823/opengl-4-core-profile-shaders-and-mfc/26956161#26956161):

> This is an example that you can use to work with mfc and opengl.
>
> Supports separate contexts per view + sharing of contexts.
>
> Here is a GITHUB example which can help the people when they start their projects.

IMHO, this answer has **absolutely no** useful content without the link. All that remains is the fact that somebody but an example on github at some point in time, and the poster believes that it is helpful. It therefore meets the criteria for not being an answer. Yet my flag came back as:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I flagged this as Very Low Quality. It has never been clearly established exactly which flag should be used for link-only answers. But I believe it has been confirmed that VLQ is one of the viable options. In one of the answers in a related MSE topic ([Can we get some consensus on what flag to use for link only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers)), a poster suggested to use VLQ for this (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183654/262723). @Shog9 commented on this answer (emphasis added by me):

> I'm not sure why this is down-voted so heavily; I can only assume that folks have some mental image of a link-only answer which isn't very low quality, and want to be able to flag it anyway. Fair enough; don't use VLQ on high-quality answers that happen to contain links (and... probably don't use any other flags either). **Note that for REAL link-only answers, VLQ works pretty well** - indeed, those that aren't outright blocked are marked as such automatically by the system, sending them into /review...

The specific answer I flagged did not go into the review queue because it had been accepted. But I believe moderators should apply the same criteria as the ones used in the review queue. There shouldn't be different rules applied just because a flag happens to be handled by a moderator.

Comment: Don't flag VLQ, it's NAA. Raise a custom flag, and make the description be " NAA as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer ". I've had significantly more success with that than basic NAA flags alone.

Comment: @JasonC I only use custom moderator flags for more complex/severe problems. Like series of bad posts by the same poster. It looks like *accepted* answers flagged VLQ (and NAA?) go to a moderator. So maybe it would be better to use the custom flag if the answer was accepted.

Comment: Confused here, previous suggestion to my question is to [use either VLQ or NAA](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273143/)

Comment: @JasonC - on the other hand, I've had two of my last three custom link-only answer flags rejected as "no evidence found", and the third was marked as "helpful", but the answer still hangs around.  There's apparently no rhyme or reason, or even consensus, on how to handle link-only answer flags, be they NAA, VLQ or custom.  I've officially given up on flagging them.

Comment: Really, I think the answer is to just accept that a little bit of fuzziness in the rules is what makes SE fun and special. Besides, if the rules were hard and fast we'd have nothing to talk about in meta.

Comment: It's fun and special until it affects your ability to flag anything else as well.

Comment: Take a giant step back, and ask yourself, does **erasing that link** make the page's coverage of the topic *better*?  Obviously not.  So stop deleting **useful information** over petty preferences!

Comment: Next up: link-only _flags_....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I declined the VLQ flag on that question, and a scant six hours later, I marked 'helpful' and deleted the same answer when it was marked as "not an answer".

[image]

Confused? That's ok.

When I looked at this flag from the 'Very Low Quality' perpective, it wasn't -- remember we have very specific criteria [about what VLQ means](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276790/16587).  Out of all the flags I process, this one is the easiest to handle.  Here's how I look at them:

- Is the Post Beyond Saving? -> Yes? Delete. No? Go to next.
- In my estimation, would it take less than five minutes to save the post? Yes? Decline. No? Accept, Delete.

I apply that metric to every VLQ flag I come across.

For "Not an answer", I apply a different set of rules:

- Does this answer attempt to *address* the question as asked? Yes/Unsure: Go to next. No? Delete.
- Would a reasonable person coming from Google (with no prior knowledge of Stack Overflow) believe this post to be an answer to the question? Yes? Decline, No? Delete.

Because of the nature of the post; it failed on the second part -- [it's not altogether clear how it's an answer to the question asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182622/16587).

Keep in mind, If I see a post flagged as "Very Low Quality", I'm not going to usually process it using other metrics simply because they may apply (unless it's really egregious and noticeable from the confines of the moderator queue).  We are strict about flags on purpose -- if we're not, it becomes too easy to keep the results from being useful.

Comment: Well, I am confused! ;) Not about your policies, but because I had seen conflicting advice in other places (including from moderators). What you're describing sounds consistent with this post I found with a search in the help center: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/93606#93606. I'll stick with this from now on. Previously, I had primarily seen the VLQ flag as a mechanism to send the post to the LQ review queue.

Comment: I like the way you defined the set of rules for the flags along with the yes/no actions. It brings a lot of clarity.

Comment: I do not understand your process: `Beyond saving: No` proceed with `fixable within five minutes: If yes, decline very low quality flag`. Some questions may be answered within five minutes. If an answer contains only a link why should someone else (for example the person flagging it) save the answer by editing it. For me this sends the wrong message to the person which created the link only answer.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree After reading George's criteria again, I sort of agree with you. I don't think I could have fixed this answer in 5 minutes. Going to a github repository, extracting the code most relevant to the question, and adding an explanation for it, would take me way longer than 5 minutes. It takes me much more than 5 minutes to write most of my answers when I already know exactly what I want to write.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree You 'should' for the same reason you answer questions: To help others. To make Stack Overflow a repository of useful knowledge.  Whether you *choose* to is up to you, but editing an existing answer to make it better is right on par with answering questions.  Unfortunately, it's very difficult to reward that action, but [I've always maintained it should be rewarded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83198/16587).

Comment: Short of rewriting the Answer, I often try to tactfully encourage the original poster to make the fix.  After all the OP may have invested more than 5 minutes in locating a dimly remembered link, and it may be simple enough to then supply the required context that mitigates the "link-only" fault.

Comment: The attitude "Confused? That's ok." is troubling to me. If its OK that one is confused, it seems a procedure change is in order, to make it less confusing. OPs intent was to bring mod attention to a post that needed attention. The fact you nuked it, supports that. It would have been better to change OPs flag to the right type, notify them, and nuke the post. IMHO.

Comment: @Nate: we can't change flag types and we don't normally accept Mis-flagged posts where VLQ is concerned because they affect metrics we use to determine what a VLQ post looks like.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thats fine. I'm just saying maybe that is an area that can be improved. We're all in agreement that the post needed attention. It just seems inefficient to decline the flag -- which gives the flagger the impression they were shouldn't have flagged it at all, not that they chose the wrong type -- in cases where the post would legitimately fit into another flag category.

Answer (score 15):

I agree with your assessment that the answer is link-only. The problem is with the flag you chose.

Link-only answers get the "not an answer" flag. SO does not make this easily discoverable. You have to read a bunch of questions and answers on meta to *eventually* figure it out. Heck, even the [faq on NAA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag) makes no mention of link-only answers!

And from reading the back and forth about the "very low quality" flag on Meta, I came to the conclusion that the **only** valid use of VLQ is if a post is gibberish. If it is not gibberish, then you have to use another flag. If you were thinking of VLQ in the first place but the post is not gibberish, *probably* NAA is what you want.

Comment: The comment from @Shog9 suggests otherwise. Also, there are arguments (including from moderators) saying that NAA flags should **not** be used for link-only answers. E.g. Robert Harvey in a comment: "A bare link to an offsite source that answers the OP's question is an answer, just not an ideal one."

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yeah, I realize Shog is saying use VLQ in that comment. However, after seeing all the "why was my VLQ flag declined" and the answers on the Meta here, I came to the conclusion that VLQ == "post is gibberish". There's disagreement between what Shog is saying there and what I'm saying.

Comment: For answers that are **literally** nothing more than links, both flags generally apply; pick whichever one appeals to you. Once you're working with a more liberal interpretation of "link only", that goes out the window: depending on what *else* is in the answer, only one flag might apply - or *neither one.* This is where context becomes so important: knowing that an answer is informed by the question and therefore useful vs. scatter-shot linking to Android docs in the hope of catching a random vote makes all the difference.

Comment: @Shog9 I understand what you are saying, but *in practice*, when someone tries to use VLQ for a link-only answer, and a mod gets to it, their flag gets declined. That's what I've learned from the questions about declined VLQ flags that have been posted on the Meta here and the responses such questions got.

Comment: In practice, the meta complaints are *heavily* skewed by a handful of people who go a bit overboard, @Louis. Mods approve the vast majority of flags, VLQ and NAA - in fact, the stats for mod-approval and community-approval (via review) are nearly identical. The big difference is that folks shrug and blame "roboreviewers" when their flags aren't acted on via review, while they blame rogue mods when their flags aren't acted on by the mod team. \

Comment: @Shog9 Look at the response [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276790/1906307), or [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275833/1906307). Those answers are saying if a post could be edited into shape, then it is not VLQ. A link-only answer *could* be edited into shape (and indeed it sometimes happens), therefore not VLQ.

Comment: If you're gonna apply that test (can be fixed by editing) then you should probably just edit, @Louis. That is, if you know enough about an answer to know that the link is 1) relevant and 2) useful, flagging it as *anything* is a disservice - you're doing more good by just adding what you know about the link to the answer than you are by asking others to delete it.

Comment: @Shog9 George [declined](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276968/1906307) a VLQ flag but accepted a NAA flag on the answer we have been discussing. How does that fit with what you are saying? Oh, and I guess he saw it as link-only, which Reto Koradi and I did, but you don't.

Comment: @Louis No. I accepted the NAA flag because I looked at the naked text (what was in the moderator queue) and it wasn't altogether clear how it answered the question.  It looked to me like someone just walking by a robbery and saying, "We need to get tough on crime."  It had *nothing* to do with the fact that it was 'link-only'.  You'll notice in my criteria, [I don't care whether it contains a 'link only' or a 'link mostly'](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276968/16587).  I don't pay attention to the link; I pay attention to the naked content in the moderator console.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker So my guess in that last sentence is not correct but the fact remains you rejected it as VLQ but accepted it as NAA, which is actually the more critical issue here.

Comment: @Louis If [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276968/16587) doesn't make sense to you, then I hope you'll bring up a new question on Meta to discuss it.  I've tried to keep it as easy to understand as possible, but if there's some way I could communicate it better, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 4):

[As Louis notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276957/declined-flag-on-link-only-answer/276959#276959), it isn't "very low quality" - chances are, if the answer was useful enough to be accepted then it's probably not VLQ.

Before you jump to flag it as "Not an Answer" though, remember this: "link only" answers are generally Not Answers, but not everything people *call* "link only" is actually link-only.

The post of mine you reference tried to make this clear via both example and analogy - the example contained no information at all, neither about the answer nor about the link; the analogy suggests that a true link-only answer is nothing more than a signpost saying, "Answer over there!". **Neither one applies to the answer you flagged.**

While that post doesn't contain an answer to the question, it does a reasonable job of describing the example that it links to, and why the author felt it would be useful to the asker. That's not much - *but it's not **nothing!*** ...And "nothing" - link-**only** - is what we're looking to avoid here.

I gave examples of this in my post too, and described them as follows:

> Yes, they're both very short, and yes, they contain links. But strip the markup, and you still get at least a little bit of useful information. Does that mean these answers should forever hang around the site? No, not necessarily - if it turns out they're just not that useful, they should probably still be removed - or at very least, down-voted so that they rank below other answers.
>
> Just remember: if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at answering the question, then it is an answer - so don't flag it otherwise, and if you do, don't complain if your flag gets declined.

Moderators tend to be really strict about this, and so should you; deleting answers based on superficial characteristics can easily become a slippery-slope ending at overbearing moderation if we're not careful. When in doubt, rely on *voting* a way to signal to both the author and to other readers that an answer is lacking - this allows for much more democratic moderation.

Comment: What piece of information in the body of the answer is usable by someone who would want to implement their own solution without having to follow the link? The first sentence amounts to "This is an example that does what you asked for." The 2nd sentence mentions that the example can use separate contexts or share contexts but since it can do either, neither seem to be key to the solution. I don't think I need to defend that the 3rd sentence, on its own, is link-only.

Comment: The fact that the answer gives an indication of what can be found at the link is certainly a positive aspect. The key question based on your guidelines that I have always used (derived from the part you quote) is: "is there useful information without the markup?". In this case, I still think the answer to that question is "no".

Comment: It describes why the link is relevant to the question, @Louis. That doesn't make it a *great* answer, but it does give readers *something* to go on. Imagine a scenario where I'm trying to decide between three answers: one is a link, one is a link along with a description of what the link is to and why I might want that, the third is a self-contained solution. Of course, I'll start with #3... But if that doesn't pan out, #2 gives me enough information to decide if it's likely to help, while #1 doesn't - what's through that door, [a prize or a goat?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall)

Comment: @Shog9 Well, then I misunderstood that post you made about answer being in another castle. I thought that the minimum needed was information that was *usable towards a solution*. Like "You should [use `undef()`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef)." Not a great answer but someone just reading the answer will know that they should use `undef()`.

Comment: [*"...but the real issue here is that **we don't know!** Even if the link was originally pointing directly to the most awesomeest answer ever for exactly the question being asked, there's nothing **in the answer itself** to even hint at what direction we're being pointed in."*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) @Louis

Comment: @Shog9 It all depends on how you understand the word "direction". You meant it more generally than I took it.

Comment: I get the feeling some of y'all think I'm exaggerating for effect when I talk about answers with **zero** information in them apart from a link. I'm not - they're a very real problem, and one we should all be working together to eliminate. Expanding that into some crusade against every short answer with a link is something else though; not a good idea, IMHO.

Comment: It's not about seeing exaggeration where there is none. The major reason raised against link-only answers is that links break. If the link ceases to point to the solution, we've lost the solution. If the answer says something ever so brief about what the key to the solution is, and the link breaks, at least we've got *something*. If the answer says that the linked solution has features A, B, C but there's no hint whatsoever as to what the key to the solution is, and the link goes dead, we've lost any actionable information. It is no use to know that once upon a time a solution did A, B, C.

Comment: Breaking links *can be* a problem, but I disagree that it's the worst aspect of such answers @Louis - if it were, flaggers would *really* be wasting their time, since it's trivial to add a page to archive.org. In short, valuable links are a problem if they break; worthless links are always a problem. When folks try to grind their way up the leaderboard by posting links to the top Google result as a way of answering while obfuscating their own ignorance... Or worse yet, spamming... It hurts everyone, right from the start - no link-breaking required.

Comment: I did not say it is the "worst aspect". The "link breaks" reason is the one that is [in the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and that is mentioned in the comment that reviewers can put when they recommend deletion of an answer. This is *the* prominent reason we give to people to avoid posting link-only answers.

Comment: ["Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - followed up by the mention of quoting relevant portions in case the link breaks. Good point on the canned deletion comment though; perhaps those could use some revising.

Comment: @Shog9 Yep, I read that. It does not invalidate what I said.