# Declined flag on link-only answer only because of the number of votes

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I recently had a declined flag on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931406/formatting-at-once-all-the-files-in-a-visual-studio-project/931425#931425). I'm guessing since the answer is accepted and has a high number of upvotes, that is the reasoning behind the declined flag.

The answer is an absolutely terrible, link-only answer:

> Tim Abell wrote a macro to do this on his [blog](http://timwise.blogspot.com/2009/01/format-all-document-in-visual-studio.html)

It should be [deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251613/542517) as NAA. Or, the relevant content from the blog post should be included in the answer.

Comment: I'm with you on this one. It is not a valid answer per the rules of this site.

Comment: `I'm guessing since the answer is accepted and has a high number of upvotes, that is the reasoning behind the declined flag` ... I wouldn't guess.  Could be a simple misclick.  But the answer doesn't seem to have a lot of value beyond the link.

Comment: However, reading the question again - I do have a guess.  The problem isn't the answer.  The problem is the question - `I am hoping there is a macro or an add-in that will do the trick.` seems to suggest a tool request question.  What kind of flag did you use?  NAA?  LQP?  Custom flag?

Comment: I used NAA, [I typically do on link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276968/542517).

Comment: @psubsee2003: Slightly reformulated. Still think it's the question?

Comment: @Deduplicator  fair point - that was a simply fix, but the top 2 answers both suck.  Neither offers anything of value except a link.  I got a little off-tangent, with the tool request point, but both answers need "fixed".

Comment: You know what's extremely strange, I flagged BOTH answers as NAA. One got marked "helpful," yet the answer still remains. The other one got flagged as "declined."

Comment: There's no benefit in deleting useful content (and an accepted answer, no less) and leaving behind an unanswered question.  That helps no one.  Editing is a far better option.  Like exactly what @RobertHarvey did.

Comment: Double standards...

Comment: And the edit still doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @mjs - Clearly the answer satisfied the OP and at least 14 others.  How is anything positive accomplished by coming in _almost 6 years later_ and saying "nope, not good enough; you guys all got it wrong"?  There needs to be a statute of limitations on these things, or something.  Perhaps something like 'NAA flags are not available for answers that are > 2 years old and marked as accepted with a score of 3 or more'.

Comment: @aroth Not a bad idea putting a statute of limitations on older posts. I wouldn't want to see any flagging disabled, because there is still plenty of bad, old content out there. But perhaps, if a post is *x* amount of years old, the only flag you can raise is to a ♦ mod.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen: On questions which aren't locked, voting/flagging for closing should always be possible.

Comment: @Deduplicator Don't disagree. Just perhaps there's a way to make it less... automated? I'd be interested to see the average age of flagged posts in the queue.

Comment: @Deduplicator Seems sensible. Its either locked for historical reasons, or should conform to the rules of the site

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A substantial portion of the moderator queue is filled with flags like this on a regular basis, where a user takes it upon himself to flag a large number of highly-upvoted, checkmarked, link-only answers using an NAA flag.

Guess what the likelihood of such flags being marked helpful is?

Some things to consider:

1. **NAA is the wrong flag to use on this.**

   When you cast an NAA flag, you're casting it because the poster is using the answer for some purpose other than answering the question, such as trying to communicate with another user or asking a new question. *If the poster isn't trying to do that, then casting an NAA flag makes no sense.*

   If you want your flag to be seriously considered in this situation, cast a custom flag, and *explain why the answer is actively harmful to the site, and therefore justifies forcible removal by a mod, despite evidence from the community that they find the answer helpful.*
2. **There are other things you can do to rescue these kinds of answers.**  You can leave a comment to the poster, link them to [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231), and ask them to summarize their answer in the post.  You can summarize the answer yourself, by making a judicious edit.  Either way, it's better than just disappearing the answer without explanation.

Comment: Now I wish I could undo my NAA flag..

Comment: Part 1 of your answer goes against what [George Stocker has to say about VLQ v. NAA answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276957/declined-flag-on-link-only-answer/276968#276968). I know you said you're not going to argue about that, so I don't want to continue that discussion, but it's important to know that there is continuous disconnect between the proper way to flag cases such as this.

Comment: And why is it harmful to the site? It's literally a link to a blog and nothing more. I don't think anymore explanation is needed. It's not an answer.

Comment: Alrighty, custom flags it is in the future (though there is not a single doubt in my mind that this answer is NAA). Regardless, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: The only reasonable response that a moderator can make to an NAA flag is deletion.  Why would they do that to a highly-upvoted, accepted answer?

Comment: Would you accept and act on other: "NAA, link preserved in other answer" / other: "NAA, other answer preserves the linked info"? Presuming those were true, naturally...

Comment: Not on the accepted answer, no.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen Why not leave a comment to the user asking them to expand on the answer because it doesn't meet the quality standards that we expect?  Also there is plenty of new bad content that could use your attention, why flag an answer from 2009 basically asking it to be removed?

Comment: @bluefeet: Maybe because he stumbled over it when searching duplicates or generally researching. Who knows... just hunting down old posts not conforming to current standards for the heck of it would be somewhat pointless though.

Comment: @Deduplicator Pointless yes, but users do it all the time.

Comment: no amount of meta explanations can stop these flags from coming. Hundreds, if not thousands 2K users who have ever been in LQ review queue and saw respective deletion reason, will simply act by example of what they saw in the queue

Comment: @bluefeet Came across it randomly, honestly didn't even look at the date. Was busy with a few other things so flagged them and went on my way.

Comment: It's accepted, and highly upvoted. What's better for the site and the community in this case? Flagging it so that a human exception handler can delete it (thus making the question no longer have an answer) or taking the time to **edit it and add a quote** and thus improving the answer?

Comment: When the only possible response to an NAA flag is to delete the answer rather than to improve it, does this not simply mean that the flagging/moderation system is insufficient and fails to take into account this edgecase? Telling people to *"use a different flag, not because of the meaning of the flag but because of the consequences of it"* just seems like a leaky abstraction to me.

Comment: @SvenSlootweg:  When you cast an NAA flag, you're casting it because the poster is using the answer for some purpose other than answering the question, such as trying to communicate with another user or asking a new question.  *If the poster isn't trying to do that, then casting an NAA flag makes no sense.*  The remedy is to cast a custom flag and explain why you're casting it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Okay, that wasn't really clear to me. Given the regularity with which such link-only answers appear, does this not warrant its own, pre-set flag? Something along the lines of "Just A Link".

Comment: @SvenSlootweg: Link-only answers are too controversial to warrant their own flag.  Even [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) has dissenting viewpoints, and it's considered canon.  And there's still the little problem of people wanting to delete answers that actually contain a solution.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen I've re-read my answer and I've read Robert Harvey's answer, and I don't see a disconnect.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I've followed your post when handling flags recently. In this case, "Is the Post Beyond Saving?" No, it isn't. "Would it take less than 5 mins to fix?" Yes. **So, it's not VLQ.** What about NAA? "Does it attempt to address the question?" Yes, it does. "Would someone coming from Google believe it to be an answer?" IMO, no. It just links somewhere else. So, it should be deleted. Then Robert Harvey states NAA is the wrong flag to use. That is the disconnect, two ♦'s having conflicting philosophies. Regardless, raising a custom flag in the future is the way I'll go from now on. :)

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen That's not conflicting because it's *in your opinion* that it doesn't answer the question.  Remember, a "Link only" answer means the answer consists solely of a link. No other nouns or verbs in the answer to discern any information.  I say in my answer not to use a "NAA" flag for something that is an attempt at an answer. providing a link and text that will solve the OP's problem is an answer, just not a very good one.  Robert is solid on the way you should go.  There are a lot of ins and outs and what-have-yous; I only mention two possible states in my answer, not all states.

Comment: I remember a Meta post that said that *NAA flags should be used for link-only answers*; your answer goes against this. What's the correct approach?

Comment: @cybermonkey:  The correct approach is to use a custom flag for those cases that are questionable, as I already explained in my answer.  In the custom flag description, justify why the post is harmful enough to be forcibly removed by a moderator.