# Bring some consistency to the flagging and deletion of link-only answers

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, link-only-answers, review-suspension

When doing our daily reviews, under "Low Quality Posts", we are asked to judge the quality of answers. If we think it should be deleted we get the following option among others:

> Should be deleted because it is a link-only answer.

Doing this automatically adds a nice informative comment to the post from the moderator as well explaining the problem. Every day, often 10+ posts that I check with that option.

Now, outside the review dashboard, I would *flag* a post for deletion because it is a link only answer with the option "not an answer". It's not just a academic discussion on potential [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), *most links in the posts I flagged were actually dead or outdated*; the answers, by definition, did not provide an answer.

To my surprise, the flags were being [turned down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/441662) by other moderators and I got banned for it. I felt rather indignant that in one screen I'm asked to delete link-only posts and in another I'm banned for it.

I [know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141851/reviewing-low-quality-posts-when-to-delete) there [have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116301/how-should-helpful-answers-that-are-just-links-be-handled) been [extensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer) discussion [regarding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276957/declined-flag-on-link-only-answer) post [quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and [link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95691/186899), but can we at least have a consistent review/flag process that both reflect the same policies? This was a little jarring.

Either:

1. remove the *review* option for closing link-only posts, or
2. add a *flag* option for closing link-only posts

That, or add a clarification somewhere because I don't know how to handle (dead) link-only posts anymore without getting a flag-ban.

Quoting [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

> So let me be clear: **this sort of response is not an answer**. If you see this, flag it. Moderators, if you see it flagged, delete it.

---

Case in point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1902124/441662#441662. Never mind the "put on hold" status, it wasn't there before (and is besides the point). Disclaimer, I posted an answer I consider proper; I was not trying to promote my own post by getting the other ones to be deleted (in fact I upvoted the only other answer that wasn't a link-only answer).

/edit it was pointed out to me that it is the nature of this example question (and hence it's "On Hold" status) to invite link-only answers and as such it is a bad example. I agree, but the point remains unless moderators think differently about flagged link-only answers on posts that don't invite link-only answers. I cannot attest to that.

Comment: I think other users cannot view your flag summary (at least I can't).

Comment: @honk Correct. Moderators can see it, normal users can't.

Comment: That last example is not a very good one. The question (and it's "put on hold" status) matter here, as this is an off-topic question asking for a library recommendation to which *only* link-only answers can be given. Arguably, you can write "good" answers on such a question (which include some example code) but this is usually just a (soon outdated) copy of whatever example is on the project's homepage. Either the question should be binned, or the answers should stay, but only deleting the answers on a "recommend be a foo" question doesn't make a lot of sense IMHO...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker. Good point, hadn't thought of it like that. The point remains however, I think, as I can still flag link-only answers on proper questions. Or do you think moderators think differently about those flags?

Comment: Link-only answers can be a really grey area. "[This link will help you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)" is obviously not great, but what if that has 1 upvote? 3 upvotes? or 6? or 10? or 30? Deleting is not the answer here, *improving it* is. I suspect these flags were denied because the answers have upvotes.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It stops being a grey area when the answers stop being answers, which is when the links are dead or heavily outdated.

Comment: Yeah, of course. But the upvotes indicate that *some* people found this useful! So why not improve, instead of delete? A link-only answer is not great, but it's better than *no* answer. Would deleting a link-only answer (with a working link) from years ago really *improve* the site, or make the site worse?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yes. Ofcourse, the answers were considered useful when the links weren't dead yet. As Shog so eloquently explained: link-only posts with links that have hope of providing information to improve with (proper title for example) should be flagged and deleted. That is just what I did. The gray area ofcourse is in the question 'what is considered enough information in a link to be able to improve the answer'.

Comment: Highly relevant from MSE: [Can we get some consensus on what flag to use for link only answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers)

Answer (score 3):

You flagged a number of posts (on the same question) as not-an-answer;

- [How to Create a Cloud Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901966/how-to-create-a-cloud-chart/17441597#17441597)
- [How to Create a Cloud Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901966/how-to-create-a-cloud-chart/19862359#19862359)
- [How to Create a Cloud Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901966/how-to-create-a-cloud-chart/7829602#7829602)
- [How to Create a Cloud Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901966/how-to-create-a-cloud-chart/1902038#1902038)
- [How to Create a Cloud Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901966/how-to-create-a-cloud-chart/1902124#1902124)

Whilst link only, they *are* an answer to the question; because the question is asking for library recommendations.

The correct behavior would have been for you to vote to close the question, and leave the answers as is. **If** the links are broken, then flag for moderator attention (rather than flagging as NAA) and say this.

For context, these are the *only* NAA declined flags on your account.

Comment: Perhaps you can add that for broken links that still have enough information to improve the answer with should be marked as "very low quality" rather than "requires moderator attention." Then the choice becomes quality check vs deleting and we have a clear decision tree for links-only posts.

Comment: In the review queues for answers we ought to have an option for indicating that the **question** has a problem.

Comment: The perpetual double-triple-quadruple standard of NAA flagging: ["Mods do not look at the question when moderating "Not an Answer" flags."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/) So why are flaggers expected to? Further, from the same link "If your flag requires a mod to evaluate an answer from the question's perspective, do not use a 'Not an Answer' flag on it." Declining the flag as "suitable for the question because it's a link request" requires **evaluation of the question's context**. This flag is utterly broken; [it needs to be overhauled](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318038/).

Comment: @BennyBottema You shouldn't go on a flagging-spree for all answers on the same question. You can refer to this Meta.SE answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264398

Comment: Well, questions about 3rd party library recommendations are *also* off topic for StackOverflow. So the question should be closed. But also, link-only answers should be closed regardless of the question. True, the best option is to simply flag the question itself. That handles all the issues.