# Flag declined for low quality answer - why?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

Recently, I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50195268/8620333) as low quality and voted to delete it:

[image]

My flag was declined, and I was surprised about this. *For me* it's clear that the answer is very low quality.

[image]

Is there an issue with this particular flag?

---

*I got declined before, but I was convinced about the reasons (even if it's not at 100%), but for this one I am not convinced.*

**UPDATE**

I usually flag those answers as low quality and they are in most of cases helpful, and that's why I got surprised about this one. Is there a particular issue with this one, or maybe I am missing something about the **low quality** reason?

Comment: @vaultah but am used to flag these answers as very low quality and flags was helpful

Comment: They're probably marked useful when the community reviews them, the answer sucks for sure but strictly speaking isn't VLQ (it's easy to understand) or NAA because of link only because with a dead link it sill contains some info.

Comment: @PeterJ so how shoud I deal with shuch answer? only downvote and delete? ... because VLQ works in most of the cases for such asnwers

Comment: Yes although you could also go to the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room to see if you can pick up support for extra delete votes. But check their rules first I'm not too familiar with them.

Comment: I'm not seeing why you think this is low quality. Looks like the extension does [what the questioner wants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50195177/73226). It might become useless in the future if the extension dies but I don't see the value in addressing that unless/until it happens. The same would apply to the other answer suggesting tamper monkey.

Comment: Regardless of the quality of the content behind the link, it's still just a link. The answer is useless if the link is unreachable for some reason. I would also have flagged as VLQ. I also usually vote to delete on this kind of link-only posts. For this to not be VLQ, OP should at least explain how it works, show some examples, demonstrate *in the answer* how this answers the question.

Comment: OK but the current state of affairs is that the link isn't unreachable so why are people deleting potentially currently useful content based on that hypothetical? The answer suggesting tamper monkey would be equally useless if that became unavailable.

Comment: Getting posts deleted is not easy.  By flagging it you are leaving it up to the judgement of somebody else whether that post requires an edit to explain why this is the golden solution or is outright wrong.  That somebody is quite unlikely to know.  You might have had better luck if you posted a comment that explained how the reader could waste a week of his life pursuing the proposed solution, but that is, ahem, unwelcoming.  Sigh.  It is unlikely to stay around for long as-is.

Comment: I suggest never using the VLQ flag. On questions, use NAA instead, they do exactly the same thing. On questions, vote to close or flag for closure, since that sends it directly to the close votes queue and VLQ on questions just sends the question to triage where others can send it to the close votes queue. 7 of my 12 declined flags are VLQ flags, most of the other ones are from when I was a new user and didn't know how to use flags.

Comment: Voting to leave open. In the suggested duplicate, the answers still stand without the link. In this case the answer depends completely on the linked resource.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: you can still install Stylish or find more info about it without the link -> the answer does not depend completely on the linked resource

Comment: @vaultah Just so we're talking about the same thing: I deliberately said the linked _resource_, Stylish. That's where the Meta questions differ IMO: GridLayout and inner joins aren't off-site resources.

Comment: I declined the flag. The answer wasn't gibberish or spam and didn't require instant deletion by a moderator, as it answers the question and could be possibly improved by the OP/others. I have updated the dupe of your question to a better answer here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276968

Comment: @SamuelLiew Are you confusing a low-quality flag with a Not An Answer flag here?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel no I'm not. Most VLQ flags are declined as users should be voting, closing, or flagging as NAA instead. However in this case it's not an NAA as well, as the issue is with the question - so vote to close the question.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I was always under the impression that VLQ also pushed it in the low-quality queue where this likely would have been deleted, with moderators only handling overflow. Shouldn't moderators handle it similarly?

Comment: No, the answer answers the question, and is not gibberish or a comment, so it shouldn't have been flagged at all in this case. The question is now closed, that is the appropriate action by the community instead. See the second comment by Peter under the question for more info.