# Not an answer flag was disputed but it should not

Tags: discussion, support, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I have flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51691620/8620333) as "not an answer":

[image]

But my flag got disputed, and I was a bit surprised, because it's more than clear to me that this is not an answer, but rather a comment.

[image]

If I refer to *[When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)*, the person is somehow **asking for clarifications** trying to guess the fix since the OP didn't provide the full code.

What is the issue then? Why is the flag not accepted?

**UPDATE**

The question and answer are deleted now (meta effect probably).

Comment: I have learned during my short period of reviewing/flagging that it is better to flag these kind of answers as VLQ. NAAs tend to get disputed, as this answer can be interprented as a very bad attempt to answer ( `Add top:0; to your css`).

Comment: @Codeer I also learned to avoid the VLQ flag here : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367420/flag-declined-for-low-quality-answer-why ... because it's not a low quality answer

Comment: The reason it was disputed is because it can be edited into an answer. A poor one yes, with assumptions maybe but still an answer. _Add `top: 0;` to your CSS_. This is possibly downvote worthy and maybe delvote worthy but this is likely why the review took the course it did.

Comment: Isn't that looks exactly like a rhetorical question? Without looking at the question and domain specific knowledge it's impossible to determine if it solves the problem.

Comment: NAA means that the answer is actually a comment (asking for clarification or something along those lines) or the answer is completely irrelevant to the question. The grey area between the two are fuzzy and can be hard to tell.

Comment: From meta.se: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131959/should-i-not-flag-a-rhetorical-question-posted-as-an-answer

Comment: @Script47 I already mention this question so it's not a duplicate ... I am dealing with a particular question here

Answer (score 5):

It's disputed because the outcome of the [Low Quality Posts review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20500756) was "Looks OK".

Comment: ok at least @rene agreed with me :p