# Flag rejected as "Declined", despite author edit, possibly due to interstitial deletion

Tags: bug, declined-flags, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

Normally, when an answer is flagged, and then the answer is subsequently edited into an appropriate answer, the flag is rejected as "Disputed" instead of "Declined". Yesterday, however, I had a flag marked as "Declined" despite the fact that it was edited by the author between me raising the flag and the post passing review as "Looks OK". That's not the expected behavior.

#### Specifics

When I flagged [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70960933/all-the-icons-in-the-navigation-bar-is-coming-black/70960978#70960978) as *NAA* at 2022-02-02 18:49:12Z, [it read](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70960978/1):

> Can you be more specific and show more details for your chosen images?

That should be a pretty clear-cut case for an *NAA* flag.

Later, at 2022-02-03 07:31:07Z, it was edited into [an appropriate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70960933/all-the-icons-in-the-navigation-bar-is-coming-black/70960978#70960978). Which is good! That's what we want!

My flag, however, was declined with the standard message:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

That's incorrect. Since the answer had been edited, it should be marked as "Disputed".

#### Hypothesis

One oddity about this particular case is that the author of the answer deleted and undeleted their answer twice between my original flag and its rejection, as can be seen on [the revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70960978/revisions). I hypothesize that this may have interfered with the logic for issuing a "Disputed" flag result.

#### Summary

Regardless, this seems like a bug: A post that has been edited since it was first flagged should be rejected as "Disputed" not "Rejected". This may, however, be a fairly narrow edge case caused by one (or more) interstitial deletions. If so, it likely doesn't affect very many flags—though it should ideally still be addressed.

Comment: Can you please add a link (i.e. to a meta discussion) which supports possibility of "Disputed" resolution for NAA flags? (I thought there  is only "helpful" with post deleted and "rejected" if post should not be deleted as NAA).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Here's a post from 4 years ago that shows an NAA flag as disputed in the flag panel: [Not an answer flag was disputed but it should not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372071)

Comment: @Nick: That does _not_ answer my question, no. The answer in that question documents the _expected_ behavior (to "implicitly _dispute_ the flag"). But that's not what happened here, even though the answer was edited. Please also be aware that I am not asking for my flag status to be changed; I am reporting this as a bug so the underlying issue can be resolved.

Comment: @zcoop98 good find... basically OP needed to get enough people to review all VLQ content to get flag to be declined. Not too hard. :)

Comment: "I am not asking for my flag status to be changed" - note that this would be technically impossible anyway

Comment: *"to "implicitly dispute the flag""* _IF_ it's edited _in review_. This post was not.

Comment: yeah, that happenend tome more than once, aand then i got the emssage your flag has been declined, this is another nails in the coffin, for flagging or reviewing. Someone some correct the handling of flags so that the mod can see the history of the answer and then should the mod also have the opportunity, to do something else than declining

Comment: @nbk Mods _can_ see the revision history, and the NAA flags can be marked helpful without deleting the post. It's not like the flag can only be declined if the post isn't deleted. Oversights still happen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Regardless, this seems like a bug

It's not a bug. Your flag was manually rejected by a moderator.

> A post that has been edited since it was first flagged should be rejected as "Disputed" not "Rejected"

NAA flags can't be disputed by mods. Whether or not it's then approved or rejected is heavily dependent on the mod; it's some times hard to notice whether a post has been edited since the flag. The standard approach is to mark it as helpful if it has been edited after the flag, provided it was valid at the time of the flag, but it being declined instead does happen. Errors also happen; mod tools deserve about 99% of the blame for this particular error, however, by having edit labels that blend in with literally everything else on the page. For context, it's a tiny, grey box that appears after the flag, on an already grey background (... in light mode anyway).

> This may, however, be a fairly narrow edge case caused by one (or more) interstitial deletions

Nope. The deletions did not affect your flag. You can easily verify this yourself by checking the timestamp; it was rejected an hour ago (at the time of writing), *not* when the post was deleted ("yesterday", according to the super inaccurate relative timestamps).

> That's incorrect. Since the answer had been edited, it should be marked as "Disputed".

No it shouldn't. That's VLQ, not NAA. If NAA flags automatically get disputed on edits, we'd waste a monumental amount of resources on the countless NAAs that get edited into *still* being an NAA. As Nick mentioned [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415820/disputed-flag-incorrectly-rejected-as-declined-possibly-due-to-interstitial-d/415821#comment893552_415820), the edit was not made from review, and consequently doesn't affect NAA flags.

**TL;DR:** no bugs here.

Comment: Is there a public wiki somewhere documenting which flags can be disputed under what circumstances? I feel like that would be useful... questions about disputed flags don't seem infrequent.

Comment: @zcoop98 No clue, but as far as I know and disregarding review edge-cases (I have no idea what review outcomes cause disputes) and messing with undocumented endpoints, mods only have a button to dispute R/A and spam flags, and nothing else.

Comment: Aha! Thank you for clarifying that. I think where I got confused was over the "implicit dispute" that seems to happen when the answer is edited by a reviewer, as [called out by @Nick in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415820/disputed-flag-incorrectly-rejected-as-declined-possibly-due-to-interstitial-d#comment893552_415820). I had read about that previously, and thought it was intended for _any_ dispute. In the future, I'll do a better job of monitoring my flags and retracting flags that are invalidated by edits. (This is something I normally try to do.)

Comment: @JeremyCaney I agree the fact we _need_ to do that is poor design, and would be more receptive of a feature request to change that than a bug report ;-)

Comment: @Zoe: That said, looking at my ["Disputed Flag" history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3025856?group=1&status=4), I'm still confused. I flagged [a link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68703040/3025856) as _NAA_, it was then edited by the author (and _only_ the author), and then marked as "Disputed". If I'm understanding your answer correctly, this shouldn't be possible, since it was flagged as _NAA_. Did the moderator tools change since then? (My last disputed _NAA_ was in August, and I've been surprised I haven't received any since.)

Comment: @JeremyCaney Again, timestamps. Note how the dispute date doesn't correspond with the edit, but rather [the completion of the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29551921). Not sure why this particular outcome results in a dispute, but this falls hard under review edge-cases. No mods were involved in that one.

Comment: @zcoop98 I don't think we have one - so I posted faq-proposed with links to this and the other question you've found. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415822/what-a-possible-resolutions-for-naa-flag/415823#415823