# What are the possible resolution states for a Not an Answer flag?

Tags: support, not-an-answer, faq-proposed

I [correctly flagged](/q/265552/) an answer as "not an answer", but when I later checked the status of the flag, I found it was "declined" because the post was edited to be a proper answer sometime after I flagged it.

What are possible outcomes for this flag type?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: I feel like this might be more useful if it was expanded to apply to more than just the NAA flag; that's more what I was looking for with [my comment about disputed flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/893553). (I think more research might be required to discover the edge cases though, because it sounds like there might be a lot of them)

Comment: @zcoop98 I don't know... Maybe NAA+VLQ together and the rest to have separate post? I think combining all flags would result in overly long post. The disputing for other flags is less common on meta and usually less controversial. That "thanks for correct NAA - declined" and "thanks for correct NAA-helpful" is far too common and confusing, "why my specific custom flag was declined" deserves individual answer in most cases.

Comment: related: [Disputed vs. helpful/declined flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253112/839601)

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 possible outcomes for the flag itself (helpful, declined, disputed) and two outcomes for the post (deleted or kept).

Helpful:

- reviewers in the corresponding review queue agreed the post should be deleted
- a reviewer chose to "Edit" the post from within review queue
- a moderator deleted the post which automatically marked any pending NAA flags as helpful
- a moderator marked the flag as helpful because the post was NAA at the time of flagging, but chose to keep the post due to some edits which made the post no longer NAA.

Disputed:

- reviewers in the corresponding queue agreed the post "Looks Okay"

Declined:

- a moderator decided the flag was not cast correctly [according to NAA rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) and chose to decline it. Note that post still can be deleted for other reasons.
- a moderator did not notice the post was significantly updated (so it no longer deserves deletion) and declined the flag. The mod may also have disagreed with it being NAA in the first place.

See [Zoe's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6296561) [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415821) for the unfortunate details of the moderator UI which make it difficult to tell when a post has been edited since being flagged.

See [Not an answer flag was disputed but it should not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372071/not-an-answer-flag-was-disputed-but-it-should-not) for exact case when flag can be disputed.

Comment: it is like everything else on this side, a work in  progress and takes to much time, a i remeber get my changed answer flagged declined more than once

Comment: This is incorrect: the LQA queue cannot decline flags.

Comment: @Alexei: For the disputed resolution, does that mean that there is a unanimous agreement for “Looks OK”? Or simply that three votes were cast for “Looks OK” (thus, potentially, overriding up to three votes for “Delete”)? My own record seems to suggest the latter. If so, that nuance may be worth calling out.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I don't have direct experience with that. Based on the question I linked as long as question is not deleted as result of the review it is marked "disputed". I thought that it is possible to get "declined" from review in case unanimous decision but based on Ryan M's comment it is not the case (added to the post by Henry Ecker's edit).

Comment: @JeremyCaney any time a review is completed with overall decision of "Looks Ok" regardless of how many "Delete" were chosen the flag is marked as disputed. This is everything from unanimous "Looks Ok" (0 delete/recommend deletions) to a 50/50 split.